# Requested resource is not available in tomcat 7

Tags: tomcat7

I have created an web application based on spring mvc After  I deployed it, in Tomcat manager the application is shown and it has been deployed successfully. But when I am accessing the web application it is giving me error saying requested resource is not available.
In log files there are no errors so far. Please help.

Regards,
Shruti

Comment: Can you add some details? What resource is not available?

Answer (score 0):

As you are using Spring MVC,

You should have SpringController in your project.

So in your each controller -

for each method there should be

a `@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)` portion.

So your application url should be something like -

```
<<web server address>>/<your deployed war file name>/<The Request mapping url>
```

i.e.

something like -

```
http://localhost:8080/samplewebproject/login
```

which will give you the requested resource.